# C++ lambda conversion -- why is candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from lambda to std::function

Tags: c++, lambda

Question about implicit lambda conversions.  I have this type:

```
class A {
 public:
  A(std::function<void(std::string)> func) {
    ....
  }
};
```

Which I believe has a valid copy constructor.

As I would like to do the following

```
A a = [](std::string param) { ... };
```

Or

```
void MyFunc(A a) { ... }  // definition

MyFunc([](std::string param) { ... });  // call
```

Yet both these yield compile error:

*note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from '(lambda at ....)' to 'std::function' for 1st argument*

Why is this? Or should this be possible?

Comment: Dummying up some simple code and trying it with gcc 8.1.1 shows that constructing the object using uniform initialization syntax works fine. I won't bother writing up an answer because it's highly likely that your real code does not resemble these isolated code snippets which only vaguely resemble C++ code, and because of that your real issue might be somewhere else. You need to take a [tour] of stackoverflow.com, go to the [help], read the instructions for creating a [mcve], and then [edit] your question, above, providing a self-contained [mcve] that demonstrates your compilation error.

Comment: [Docs claim it should work for `lambda`s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (emphasis added): "Instances of `std::function` can store, copy, and invoke any Callable target -- functions, ***lambda expressions***, bind expressions, or other function objects, as well as pointers to member functions and pointers to data members." It includes an example which stores such a `lambda` directly, so it should work just fine.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Provided code exhibit the issue. but error message is not clear and misleads OP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that only one user conversion is allowed and you need two:

- lamba -> `std::function` -> `A`.

Both

```
A a{[](std::string) {}};
MyFunc({[](std::string) {}});
```

work.

Comment: Ahh ok I suspected this.

Is there any way to specify a lambda conversion in the A class? `A(lambda x) { ... }` or something?

Comment: `template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<A, std::decay_t<T>>::value, int> = 0> A(T&&)` might help.