# Conversion from lambda to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, std-function

I created this class so I could have a value of any type which is either fixed or recalculated everytime it's used:

```
template<typename T>
class Value {
    private:
    bool fixed;
    union {
        T value;
        std::function<T()> get;
    };
    public:
    Value(const T& value) : fixed(true), value(value) {}
    Value(const std::function<T()>& get) : fixed(false), get(get) {}
    Value(const T *pointer) : Value([pointer]() { return *pointer; }) {}
    ~Value() {}
    operator T() { return fixed ? value : get(); }
};
```

All the following expressions seem to work fine:

```
Value<double> a = 2.2;
double b = 1.;
double c = a;
Value<double> d = &b;
Value<int> e = Value<int>([]() { return 1.; });
```

But when I try to do:

```
Value<double> f = []() { return 1.; };
```

a compilation error is triggered:

```
error: conversion from 'main()::<lambda()>' to non-scalar type 'Value<double>' requested
```

You can try this example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bf8srh).

Why does assigning work for `T` and not `std::function<T()>` and how can I make it so it does?

Note: I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51795627/5308892) but I didn't become clear to me how to fix the issue without having to explicitly call the constructor like I did for `Value<double> e`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Just added a link to the platform I'm testing this on.

Comment: in your godbolt link the line reads `Value<int> e = Value<int>([]() { return 1; });` while the one here `Value<double> e = Value<int>([]() { return 1.; });` is an error

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Should be fixed. I converted everything to doubles to simplify the question but forgot to change it on godbolt.

Comment: you could write `auto f = Value<int>([]() { return 1; });` If you are worried about spelling out the type twice. Its basically the same, and works ;)

Comment: I'd suggest replacing the innards of this class with `std::variant`. Also, for the first two constructors, since `Value` wants to "takes ownership of" (i.e. saves) the argument, you should make the arguments by-value (no reference qualifier) and `std::move` them into the data members. That way, the caller controls whether to copy or to move, instead of you forcing a copy.

Comment: @HTNW sorry, nitpick: Your usage of "take ownership" is a bit misleading imho. The constructor makes a copy. No transfer of ownership of a resource is made here.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 The end result of construction is an object which "owns" a `T` or a `std::function<T()>`. The "natural order" of things, or what the class "wants", is to "take" ownership via by-value parameters on the constructors. By making the parameters `const&`, we have a mismatch between a value which can't be moved and the design of the class "wanting" to take the value and own it. The mismatch is resolved with a copy, which may have a big time cost (or be impossible). Make the parameters by-value and things go more smoothly, and we no longer need a copy.

Comment: @HTNW ok thanks, my misunderstanding ;) I was mislead by the `int`/`double` examples. Now I also understand the "" in your original comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does assigning work for T and not std::function<T()> and how can I make it so it does?

Your code does not use assignment, but [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) and

> In addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must produce T directly from the initializer, while, e.g. direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of T's constructor.

So to make it work you have to make your ctor to accept lambda directly (this is simplified example):

```
template<typename T>
class Value {
    std::function<T()> get;    
public:
    
    template<class Y>
    Value(Y lambda ) : get( std::move( lambda ) )  {}
};
```

[live code](https://ideone.com/1OIcOL) You probably want to add restriction using `std::enable_if` or concept if C++20 is allowed to this ctor as well as in this form this constructor would try to accept everithing other overloads would not and may produce cryptic errrors. And according to this [enable_if template param is lambda (with particular signature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859115/enable-if-template-param-is-lambda-with-particular-signature) it could be as simple as

```
template<class Y, typename = decltype(std::declval<Y&>()())>
Value(Y lambda ) : get( std::move( lambda ) )  {}
```

which supports C++14. Here is [yet another live example](https://ideone.com/rwqkZy) where you can see that this constructor is not used for initializer of type `int`:

```
 Value<double> d2 = 123;
```

> prog.cpp:9:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Y = int]: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
> Value(Y lambda ) : get( std::move( lambda ) )  {}

Comment: Here's the original example with this answer + enable_if constraints applied: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91ef3d3829cd423d

Comment: @tangy thanks, you should mention that requires C++17

Answer (score 4):

A lambda is not a `std::function`.  That means when you do

```
Value<double> f = []() { return 1.; };
```

you need to convert `[]() { return 1.; }` into a `std::function`, which is a user defined conversion, and then you need to convert that `std::function` into a `Value<double>`, which is another user defined conversion.  That's two user defined conversion when you are only ever allowed up to one such conversion.  This is why the code fails to compile.

Comment: You can get around it by using the other constructor syntax `Value<double> f { []() { return 1.; } };`, which counts as an explicit constructor call and therefore not an extra conversion.

Comment: Can I make it work by modifying the class though?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yes, with that you have one user defined conversion from the lambda type to a `std::function`, and then that `std::function` object is used for the direct initialization.

Comment: @cabralpinto You can.  You would need to add a template constructor to `Value` that takes any type of callable.  That would let you take the lambda as is, and then you'd be okay.

Comment: Is it possible you can edit your answer to show those changes? I'm quite new to C++ and am still trying to figure out templates.

Comment: @cabralpinto Slava has added added such a work around in their answer.  It still needs more work, but it'll get you started. unfortunately you are getting to template meta-programming territory and it is not a fun place for beginners.  Heck, I've been using it for years and it still stumps me from time to time.